# Divide a video output

Tags: videos

I will soon be in charge of multiple screens for scene at a concert. Those screens are centralised and a video output will be give to me. I'am looking for a way to divide this video output into two virtuals parts in my computer. The left part and the right part.

The goal is to show different visuals on the two parts.

Thank you for your help